# update single record in access

Tags: ms-access, records

I made a fairly simple database in access that contains the stock, customers, sales order, sales order item tables from a fictional company.

I want to reduce the stock level by using a customer/sales order form. however, if I try to do this, it reduces the "stock_level" from all records within the form.

I tried the following query to do it:

```
UPDATE stock 
  INNER JOIN Sales_order_item ON stock.stock_ID = Sales_order_item.fk2_stock_ID 
SET stock.Stock_level = [stock]![Stock_level]-[Quantity_Ordered] 
WHERE (((stock.stock_ID)=[Forms]![Sales Order SubForm]![fk2_stock_ID]));
```

And this is the stock table:

[image]

thanks for looking into it, I'm completely stuck on this matter!

Comment: Those screen shots are not particularly helpful as you've cut off some key info.  Switch the query to "SQL View" then copy and paste the SQL text into your question.

Comment: the sql view shows:

UPDATE stock INNER JOIN Sales_order_item ON stock.stock_ID = Sales_order_item.fk2_stock_ID SET stock.Stock_level = [stock]![Stock_level]-[Quantity_Ordered]
WHERE (((stock.stock_ID)=[Forms]![Sales Order SubForm]![fk2_stock_ID]));

Comment: Actually, your query looks OK to me.  For example, if `[Forms]![Sales Order SubForm]![fk2_stock_ID] = 2` and `Quantity_Ordered = 6`, then your query would reduce the `Stock_Level` of chairs from 50 to 44.

Comment: It is possible that when and how often you are calling the query could be causing problems.  It still feels like there is more going on here that you are leaving out.

Comment: I actually changed it to the following:
UPDATE stock INNER JOIN Sales_order_item ON stock.stock_ID = Sales_order_item.fk2_stock_ID SET stock.Stock_level = [stock]![Stock_level]-[Forms]![Sales Order Form]![somethingsubform].[Form]![Quantity_Ordered]
WHERE (((stock.stock_ID)=[Forms]![Sales Order Form]![somethingsubform].[Form]![fk2_stock_ID]));

it does works somewhat, but it only reduces the stocklevel of the first product in the subform.

if you need more info to work on, please tell me!

serious thanks for trying to help me out though!

Comment: I think there could be issues with the approach you are using itself.  I don't think you'll be able to do what you want just by changing this query.  You may want to ask a new question (referencing this one) with what your overall intentions are.